# How to display any activity only once without using shared preferences?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to display term of service in my app only once when app launched without using shared preference because If user clear app data it will display again.

Comment: You would need to store the "has this person seen the terms of service?" flag on your server, then.

Comment: @CommonsWare is correct. The only way to ensure this does not display later is to store that in a database for each user account. Nothing else (cookies, etc.) will truly persist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve can only be achieved with flags.

1. Shared preference -
   Which you don't want to use it's okay.
2. Use any other database like firebase
   You don't need to add email login etc firebase create ID for every new user so now store your flag inside this.
   Simple.
   So it wil not deleted too.
   But user should logged in with e-mail if want to get retrieved the data.